# Colourise unfilled svgs with Sharp

Tags: node.js, svg, colors, sharp

I want to use [Sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) to colorise SVG files without a fill attribute (these look black in my browser) and export the result as a png. Currently I'm using the following process:

```
sharp().modulate({ lightness: 50 }).tint({ r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }).png();
```

This correctly colourises the SVG as red. However if I try the same approach with yellow:

```
sharp().modulate({ lightness: 50 }).tint({ r: 255, g: 255, b: 0 }).png();
```

I get a grubby brown colour, whereas the following (note the `lightness` change from 50 to 100) works as expected:

```
sharp().modulate({ lightness: 100 }).tint({ r: 255, g: 255, b: 0 }).png();
```

So it seems that `lightness` value needs to be varied depending on the colour.

Given an RGB target colour, how can I calculate what the `lightness` value should be, or is there a better approach?

Comment: I imagine you need to convert from sRGB to linearRGB. There's some [pseudo code in the SVG 1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ColorInterpolationProperties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading around the issue and seeing [this discussion](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1720), I decided to use a different approach.

Rather than working with modulate and tint, I generate a rectangle the size of my image and of the required overlay colour, and composite this with my source image with blend mode `in`:

```
const writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('my_image.png')
readableStream.pipe(sharp().resize(200, 200).composite([{
 input: {
  create: {
   width: 200,
   height: 200,
   channels: 4,
   background: { r: 255, g: 0, b: 0 }
  }
 }, blend: 'in'
}])).pipe(writableStream);
```